# How to get all sections by name in the sectionGroup applicationSettings in .Net 2.0

Tags: c#, configuration, mono, .net-2.0, configurationsection

Here's the idea I had:

I want a small executable to have an app.config file with multiple sections that are situated under the sectionGroup "applicationSettings" (not "appSettings", I don't need to write to the file). Each section would have a name corresponding to a module that should be loaded if set.

Here's an example:

```
   <configuration>
     <configSections>
       <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
         <section name="Executable" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
         <section name="FirstModule" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
       </sectionGroup>
     </configSections>
     <applicationSettings>
       <Executable>
         <setting name="MyFirstSetting" serializeAs="String">
           <value>My awesome feature setting</value>
         </setting>
       </Executable>
       <FirstModule path="path to the modules assembly">
         <setting name="ImportantSettingToTheModule" serializeAs="String">
           <value>Some important string</value>
         </setting>
       </FirstModule>
     </applicationSettings>
   </configuration>
```

Now if I define the FirstModule section, I want my application to load its assembly. If the section is not defined, the module should not be loaded. This should be true for not only one module but a not yet defined number of them.

So I basically need to find out about the defined sections at runtime. How would I do that?

In addition I want this to become a portable executable (= it has to run on Mono as well) that is backwards compatible to .NET 2.0.

It might be interesting to have a look at the project on GitHub (currently at [this commit](https://github.com/textquell/rhenus-spring/commit/937151e91be551808c7fdc9dcd91750f24a0b0a2)).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Take a look at the [`ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) function to load in your configuration file.

Then on the [`System.Configuration.Configuration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Configuration.Configuration);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) class that you'll get back from `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration` you'll want to look at the `SectionGroups` property.  That'll return a [`ConfigurationSectionGroupCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsectiongroupcollection.aspx) in which you'll find the `applicationSettings` section.

In the `ConfigurationSectionGroupCollection` there will be a `Sections` property which contains the `Executable` and `FirstModule` [`ConfigurationSection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsection.aspx) objects.

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(pathToExecutable);
var applicationSettingSectionGroup = config.SectionGroups["applicationSettings"];
var executableSection = applicationSettingSectionGroup.Sections["Executable"];
var firstModuleSection = applicationSettingSectionGroup.Sections["FirstModule"];
```

You will want to check for `null` after getting the `ConfigurationSectionGroupCollection` object or `ConfigurationSection` objects.  If they are null they don't exist in the configuraiton file.

You can also get the sections by using [`ConfigurationManager.GetSection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.getsection.aspx)

```
var executableSection = (ClientSettingsSection)ConfigurationManager
    .GetSection("applicationSettings/Executable");
var firstModuleSection = (ClientSettingsSection)ConfigurationManager
    .GetSection("applicationSettings/FirstModule");
```

Again, if the objects are `null` they don't exist in the configuration file.

To get a list of all the section names and groups you could do:

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

// use the line below instead if you want to load an app.config for a
//   different application other than the one the code is running in
// var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(pathToExecutable);

var names = new List<string>();
foreach (ConfigurationSectionGroup csg in config.SectionGroups)
    names.AddRange(GetNames(csg));

foreach (ConfigurationSection cs in config.Sections)
    names.Add(cs.SectionInformation.SectionName);

private static List<string> GetNames(ConfigurationSectionGroup configSectionGroup)
{
    var names = new List<string>();

    foreach (ConfigurationSectionGroup csg in configSectionGroup.SectionGroups)
        names.AddRange(GetNames(csg));

    foreach(ConfigurationSection cs in configSectionGroup.Sections)
        names.Add(configSectionGroup.SectionGroupName + "/" + cs.SectionInformation.SectionName);

    return names;
}
```

Comment: That helped a lot, thank you very much. I would give two upvotes for directly referring to my example, but I can't... :(

Comment: No problem, glad to help, you may want to see my latest edit.  I included some information on `ConfigurationManager.GetSection`.  Which if you don't need to perform any other actions on the configuration file, is usually the preferred way for accessing the configuration file.

Comment: Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None); - this will open the config for the current app. no need to know exe path.

Comment: Thanks @timothy!  Excellent tip... saved me lots of searching.

Comment: @JGinSD: I've used your code for solving my issue (stackoverflow.com/questions/68541684) but I still don't get it: why a recursive function call???

Comment: @Dominique `ConfigurationSectionGroup`s can be nested