# How do I read the "System.ServiceModel" configuration section group from a class library?

Tags: c#, wcf, wif

Is there any way to access the "System.ServiceModel" client configuaration i.e. app.config in a class based (dll) project?

Comment: It's not really clear what *class based project* means. Is it a project with output type "Class Library", i.e. a DLL?

Comment: Yes. Its needs to read for a dll.

Comment: If your dll "consumer" is an asp.net application/website, just place the configuration part into your web.config.

Comment: See this, it can help you: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14963870/how-to-get-all-sections-by-name-in-the-sectiongroup-applicationsettings-in-net](how-to-get-all-sections-by-name-in-the-sectiongroup-applicationsettings-in-net)

Comment: No. Its read (WCF) system.servicemodel client configuration. Secondly, dll is not consumed in asp.net application or website.

Answer (score 8):

`ConfigurationManager.GetSection(string)` lets you open a section from the executing application's app.config or web.config. but `system.ServiceModel` isn't a section, it's a section group. `ConfigurationManager` doesn't provide a way to get a section group.

There are ways to get to a `Configuration` without `ConfigurationManager`, but it's a little messy because you have to distinguish between an app.config and web.config.

But if you can skip past `system.ServiceModel` to the actual configuration group that you want then it's really easy because you can use `ConfigurationManager`. For example,

```
var section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.serviceModel/client");
```

Or you can make it strongly typed:

```
var section = (ClientSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.serviceModel/client");
```

or

```
var behaviorSection = 
    (BehaviorsSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.serviceModel/behaviors");
```

Comment: I want to used the WCF Client configuaration defined in config.app. Its not to read/access the user defined value/group.